# FragmentTransacion com o Fragment Activity

Tags: android, android-fragment, navigation-drawer

Eu estou utilizando o NavigationDrawer para exibir as opções de página, eu adaptei uma delas para FragmentActivity para a chamada de algumas funções derem certo. Porém quando declaro a transação das telas, não permite deste modo, apenas com o Fragment sem o Activity junto. Assim não funciona o FragmentTransaction.

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =  fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, mFeedFragment);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: Olá. Poderia explicar melhor o que quer dizer com "não permite" e "não funciona"?

Comment: Assim, se usar o FragmentActivity eu não posso chamar usando o replace, o que só aceita Fragment conforme mostra tenho q mudar, não sei se tem como adapte para o q eu desejo. Vendo a possibilidade mudei para findById que retoma o que eu quero usar, o corretor marca justamente q devo usar dai o FragmentActivity para o que estou usando se está certo, não sei o Manager e transaction permitem isso não achei nada na documentação.